# ICS to uppdate this and future in recurring calendar event

Tags: calendar, icalendar, recurring-events

I am trying to programmatically create icalendar events by creating an ICS file and sending them via email to the attendees. I want to be able to create a recurring event, which works fine.
Now I also want to be able to update these events. If I try to update a single occurrence from the whole event series using `UID`, `RECURRENCE-ID` and `SEQUENCE`, it again gets updated fine.

But I am unable to figure a way out to update `this and future` events. I tried using `VALUE=THISANDFUTURE` with `RECURRENCE-ID` but only the event pointed to by `RECURRENCE-ID` gets updated. I also do not want to go the "delete the series and create two new ones" way because to do that I'd have to send cancellation emails to the `ATTENDEES` first and then new events' invites.

I came across the property `RELATED-TO` which might be relevant here but am unable to understand what it does and how to use it to get the result that I want. Can anyone provide me some direction?

Answer (score 0):

Usage according to the RFC5545 specification ( https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.2.13) is with RANGE, not VALUE

```
 RECURRENCE-ID;RANGE=THISANDFUTURE:19980401T133000Z
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but that doesn't work either. Looks like send two separate email - 1. for updating original recurrence pattern to end at the start date from where we want to update this and future 2. for creating a new series of events starting at the start date from where we want to update this and future and ending at the original recurrence end date is the only solution